# Initialise a variable with a specific date in a specific format

Tags: bash, date

I want to initialise a variable with yesterday's date in a specific format . ex---if today is 15 Feb, then variable should be-- var=Feb 14

`date -d"-1day" +"%b %d"` is not working. I don't know whether the syntax is incorrect or why else it is not working.

What is the correct way to use it?

Answer (score 3):

Put `$( )` around the command when assigning, eg:

```
#!/bin/bash

hi=$(date -d'-1day' +'%b %d')

echo "$hi"
```

Works.

*Updated as per geirha's comment.*

Comment: it does not work. it says date: --d : illegeal option. i am using putty

Comment: What is the exact way you are using it then? (Update your original post)

Comment: var=$(date -d"-1day" +"%b %d"); echo $var

Comment: That usage works fine for me.

Comment: but it shows the message-> date: --d : illegeal option...any other way of doing it?

Comment: You mention "I am using putty", are you connecting to an Ubuntu server ? Also please note that it's single "-d", not "--d" .

Comment: Works fine here as well.  My guess is that you are connecting to a non Ubuntu server that does not have the date program from the coreutils package.

Comment: @Ward good practice dictates that for that simple example you should use a lowercase variable name (since its not an environment variable), use the newer and saner `$(..)` syntax instead of backticks, and lastly, put double quotes around the expansion of the variable. `echo "$hi"`, not `echo $hi`.

Comment: @geirha Thanks for the tips, I don't often program in bash ^^